# PhpStorm indexing hangs on Scanning library PHARS

Tags: phpstorm

After `composer install` PhpStorm starts indexing and hangs on "Scanning library PHARS".

[image]

It doesn't finish after few hours.

Comment: You may watch https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-57899 ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress.

Answer (score 12):

you can add *.phar to Settings -> Editor -> File types -> Ignored files and folders

[image: Ignored files and folders]

or alternatively to Settings -> Directories -> Exclude files

[image: Directories]